# Returning all individual values from each element (tag) of my observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I use breeze inside my projet and have an observable array which gets all my posts. Each of these posts have a tags observable containing several words (tags comma separated).

```
Public class Post
{
    Public int Id { get; set; }
    Public string Description { get; set; }
    Public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all individual tags from my observablearray.

So for example:

- 1: cobol, java, csharp
- 2: java, sybase
- 3: cobol, pascal

I need the result of: cobol, java, csharp, sybase, pascal

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't be sure I understood you right. Is that what you are looking for ?

```
var posts = [
     {Tags: 'cobol, java, csharp' },
     {Tags: 'java, sybase' },
     {Tags: 'cobol, pascal' }
];


var result = ko.utils.arrayMap(posts, function(post) {
    return post.Tags;
}).join(', ');


console.log(ko.toJSON(result));
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NN6uw/)